# How to create and maintain JSF composite component jar with netbeans and ant

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, netbeans, ant

I would like to create and maintain a jsf composite component packaged in a jar with the
IDE Netbeans.

I created a Web Profile Project with Netbeans that produces a war file, it is pretty convenient approach to develop and deploy a component. After the component is finished I would like to package it in a jar file and distribute it with the other projects.

So I have written this ant script to package the component in the appropriate format.

```
    <target name="-post-dist">

    <property name="jar.build" value="build/jar-dist"/>
    <property name="jar.dist" value="dist/outputjar.jar"/>

    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" file="${jar.build}" quiet="true"/>
    <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" file="${jar.dist}" quiet="true"/>


    <mkdir dir="${jar.build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${jar.build}/META-INF"/>
    <copydir src="build/web/resources" dest="${jar.build}/META-INF/resources/"/>


    <jar destfile="${jar.dist}">
        <fileset dir="${jar.build}"/>
    </jar>

</target>
```

I can place the generated jar in another project and it works (It is currently a small component without managed beans).

The problem is, I have to do it manually. I want to add my component project as a reference to other projects so they will get the jar automatically. I cannot link my component project as Project Reference in Netbeans because the project is from type webproject.

So what can I do? 
Btw: Is my approach to create and maintain JSF components valid?

p.s.: I have to use Netbeans and ant. (Eclipse and Maven is not possible to use.)

Comment: Have you tried creating a project that automatically generates a JAR instead of a web profile project?

Comment: I don't do Netbeans (hence no answer here), but in Eclipse, such a project is called "Web Fragment Project" (which is basically a "Java Project" with a precreated `/META-INF/resources` folder and optionally a `web-fragment.xml`; otherwise you can always just manually create the folder+file). Point is, do not create it as a web project! Just create it as a normal Java project with the right folder structure ready (basically .. `/META-INF/resources` is all you need). Then you can easily reference it in a real web project.

Comment: it is really uncomfortable to create a normal java project and to recreate the appropriate structure (META-INF/resources). I have to switch to the files view and cannot work in the project view. I have to switch always between the two views.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this in Eclipse. Even more, you don't need any ant build file at all. Just export-as-JAR option and/or referencing in *deployment assembly* of web project suffices.

Comment: hmm, if I use simple java project, I cannot use Java EE wizards in netbeans e.g. to create a ManagedBean...

Comment: +1 for Ant `-post-dist` task idea (build additional JAR instead of just from WAR). I adapted it (to also copy a `faces-config.xml` and some JSF managed bean classes into the shared JAR) in a multi-project test ensemble and it works fine [except for NetBeans8.1 complaining about the referenced CC](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257684). It runs nevertheless in the client web app. The big advantage of this approach is that one can keep the "upstream" Web App Project running with all NetBeans JSF support and test it separately. Big con is lack of JRebel reloading in client web app.